# Nested Jinja2 for loops

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm passing 2 variables (3 including a simple one) to some Jinja from a python script.

On certain runs I want to generate a list with links.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <table>

        {% if packageURLs is defined %}
            {% for x in packageURLs: %}
                <a href="{{ x }}">
            {% endfor %}


            {% for i in packagesList: %}
                <tr><td>{{ i }}</td></tr>

            {% endfor %}


        {" else "}


            {% for i in packagesList: %}
                <tr><td>{{ i }}</td></tr>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}

        </a>
    </table>
</body>
```

for each 'packageURLs' I want to add a  tag then some table tags for 'packages' List. What's happening though is its generating HTML but completing each individual for loop first. So I end up with half a page full of links then another with table rows. How can I have it iterate through both initially?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <table>

        {% if packageURLs is defined %}
            {% for i,x in packagesList  %}
                <a href="{{ x }}">
                    <tr><td>{{ i }}</td></tr>
                </a>
            {% endfor %}

        {" else "}

            {% for i in packagesList: %}
                <tr><td>{{ i }}</td></tr>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}


    </table>
</body>
```

Which is populated using zip() in the python script:

```
f = t.render(title=dataType,packagesList=zip(Info,packageURLs),packageURLs=packageURLs)
```

I kept the last variable out of laziness as a check since I still want to only execute those different chunks sometimes.